# Autocomplete não exibe os dados do formulário php

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

Estou com um problema em um site onde o autocomplete que busca os dados do banco não está retornando o valor da página php onde o envio o GET.
Quando vou no console apresenta erro na seguinte linha.

```
document.getElementById("dados_essenciais").innerHTML = con_consulta.responseText;
```

javascript

```
function autoComplete(){
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    var con_consulta;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        con_consulta = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        con_consulta = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    con_consulta.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (con_consulta.readyState == 4 && con_consulta.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("dados_essenciais").innerHTML = con_consulta.responseText;
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    var cli_codigo = document.getElementById("cli_codigo").value;

    con_consulta.open("GET", "handle.php?cli_codigo="+cli_codigo,true);
    con_consulta.send(null);
}
```

CNPJ Razão Social

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>CNPJ <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="cnpj" onblur="autoComplete();" id="cli_codigo" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://primula.grupoprestarh.com.br/view/ordem-servico/loading.gif" alt="" id="loading" class="loadingModal" style="display: none">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Razão Social</label>
            <div class="dados_essenciais">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="codigo" value="">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="razaosocial" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro é porque você está buscando um elemento com o id `#dados_essenciais` que não existe. Em vez disso existe um elemento com uma classe `.dados_essenciais`.

Ou você troca o `class` por `id` em:

```
<div class="dados_essenciais">
```

Ou muda o código de:

```
document.getElementById("dados_essenciais").innerHTML = con_consulta.responseText;
```

Para:

```
document.querySelector(".dados_essenciais").innerHTML = con_consulta.responseText;
```

Mas tem que ver se a classe `.dados_essenciais` é a primeira na página, senão ele irá buscar outra que seja a primeira. Mas seria melhor você colocar um id, caso existam vários elementos com a mesma classe e ele possua formatação via CSS ou outro tipo de funcionalidade:

```
<div id="dados_essenciais" class="dados_essenciais">
```